# Conjugaison du verbe aider

Tags: accord, conjugaison

J'aimerais savoir dans la phrase suivante,  quelle est la règle utilisée pour conjuguer le verbe aider :
" j'ai consulté un psychothérapeute, qui m'a aidée à..."
Source : livre : "les maladies psychiques "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La règle est la suivante :

> Aider quelqu'un à faire quelque chose.

Lorsqu'un complément d'object direct précède un verbe conjugué à un temps composé (passé composé, plus-que-parfait, etc.) il faut faire l'accord du participe passé.

Ici, la personne consultant le psychothérapeute est une femme,  donc :

> J'ai consulté un psychothérapeute, qui m'a aidé**e** à...

Si c'était un homme qui parlait, on écrirait :

> J'ai consulté un psychothérapeute, qui m'a aidé à...

Notons qu'il n'y a aucune différence phonétique. Il existe évidement des cas où l'accord s'entend. Ex :

> L'assiette que tu as mise sur la table est...

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks a lot !

Comment: Le "-ée" ne se prononce-t-il pas un peu plus "long" que le "-é" ?

Comment: @radouxju I am not a native:-)! As far as I know there is no any difference since e is mute. May be a native could verify it.

Comment: Maybe this would be worth a question. I am a native but from Belgium, so this could be a "regional" stuff

Comment: @radouxju Je viens de poster une question : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42617/prononciation-aid%c3%a9e-contre-aid%c3%a9

Comment: merci, +1 pour la question