# Prononciation : "aidée" contre "aidé"

Tags: prononciation, accord, participe-passé

> J'ai consulté un psychothérapeute, qui m'a aid**ée** à...

> J'ai consulté un psychothérapeute, qui m'a aid**é** à...

> Nous avons consulté un psychothérapeute, qui nous a aid**és** à...

> Nous avons consulté un psychothérapeute, qui nous a aid**ées** à...

Le "-ée" se prononce-t-il pas un peu plus "long" que le "-é" ou non ? Existe-t-il un régionalisme dans ce cas ? Personnellement, je crois qu'il n'y a pas de différence phonétique ; à savoir **ɛde** pour toutes les formes. Est-ce que je suis correct ?

Comment: À ma connaissance, il n'y a absolument aucune différence à l'oral, mais je ne poste pas en tant que réponse car je ne suis pas sûr de l'existence d'éventuels régionalismes.

Comment: Au théâtre, le **ée** est prolongé, et parfois plus accentué encore dans les tirades de boulevard … mais c’est du théâtre où l’on peut savourer l’habileté des comédiens. Cela peut se retrouver dans les prétoires, mais je ne me souviens pas avoir perçu cette nuance dans la rue. « J'ai consulté un psychothérapeute, qui m'a aidée à … » à moins d'être cabotine, le *ée* ne sera pas prolongée

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Il y a une variation régionale, oui.

Historiquement, les séquences voyelles + schwa en fin de mot ont donné naissance à des voyelles longues quand ces schwas finaux ont cessé d'être prononcé. Cette distinction permettait effectivement de différencier le masculin et le féminin des participes passés (aidé /ede/ aidée /edeː/, vu /vy/ vue /vyː/, ébahi /ebai/ ébahie /ebaiː/) mais aussi des formes verbales finies (il voit /ivwa/ ils voient, qu'il voie /iwwa:/) et des noms (le bout /bu/ la boue /buː/).

La plupart des dialectes du français ont perdu ces distinctions de longueur durant le 19ème siècle, mais elle se maintiennent toujours dans le nord-est de la francophonie européenne, dans un arc allant de la Belgique à la Suisse en passant par la Lorraine et l'Alsace.

Dans ces variétés, la différence est marquée, les voyelles longues étant deux fois plus longues que les voyelles courtes, et parfois diphtonguées ([edeːj]). Dans un étude comparative des français de Suisse et de France, Grosjean et al. a trouvé que dans des paires de mots comme ami/amie, pointu/pointue, aimé/aimée, les participants parisiens ont prononcés la voyelle finale des mots masculins avec un longueur moyenne de 169 ms et celle des mots féminins avec une longueur moyenne de 178 ms (on considère en générale qu'une distinction de longueur doit être de plus de 10% pour être perceptible). Les participants suisses, par contre, ont prononcés les mots masculins avec une voyelle finale d'une longueur moyenne de 150 ms, tandis que celle des mots féminins avait une longueur moyenne de 342s, soit une augmentation de 128%!

La même étude a aussi trouvé que, présentés avec un mot prononcé avec voyelle longue (par exemple, /ʒɔliː/), les suisses l'identifiaient correctement (comme étant, dans mon exemple, jolie) dans 86% des cas, tandis que les parisiens ne le faisaient que dans 43% des cas (en d'autres termes, en répondant au hasard entre les deux choix donnés, joli et jolie).

Ces distinctions de longueur sont donc produites et perçues par les suisses (et donc porteuse de sens), mais ni produites ni perçues par les parisiens.

(Pour donner une idée de la distinction à ceux qui ne l'ont pas, je prononce "Brie" identiquement à "brille", et les oppose à "bris")

Source: François Grosjean et al. *Long and short vowels in Swiss French: Their production and perception*, 2007, DOI: https://doi.org/10.1017/S0959269506002626

Comment: merci pour cette réponse complète. Pourriez-vous préciser ce que vous entendez par "schwa" ?

Comment: @radouxju Le e-muet, quand il n'est pas muet.

Answer (score 1):

Non, il n'y a aucune différence en Français de France.

Comment: Donc il existe absolument *aucun régionalisme* où la prononciation est différente?